# Problems facing in making urls seo friendly and removing extensions from files in PHP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, seo

I am facing problems in making urls seo friendly and removing extensions from php files. If i use one of it either removing extensions or making urls seo friendly it works fine but in case if i use both of these only upper part of .htaccess works for these both.

My .htaccess code is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks    
Options -Multiviews    
RewriteEngine on    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/$ $1.php    
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/$ /$1/$2.php    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$    
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]    

RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ vendorlist.php?bcat=$1     
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /vendor.php?bcat=$1&vendor=$2
```

It only remove extensions if i use it written as above. In case using seo friendly urls it gives an error 404. But if i change position like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks    
Options -Multiviews    
RewriteEngine on    

RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ vendorlist.php?bcat=$1     
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /vendor.php?bcat=$1&vendor=$2     

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/$ $1.php    
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/$ /$1/$2.php    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$    
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Then it only make urls SEO friendly. No extension removal works.

Please help me out of this, Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php 

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

**Source:**
 - [User:Dave/Web Hack Notes (Non-Wiki)#Prettier URLs Through .htaccess](http://telecafe.org/smw/User:Dave/Web_Hack_Notes_%28Non-Wiki%29#Prettier_URLs_Through_.htaccess)

The example shown in the code box above is just one suggestion. It's actually worth reading through the several tutorials found at the above link (which points to a wiki page I maintain).